# ASP Net Core - Mixing External Identity Provider with Individual User Accounts for Audit Tracking

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-identity

I have created a default ASP Net Core MVC web app with Individual User Accounts. I added a custom UserID INT field to the AspNetUsers table and linked this as a foreign key to all my other custom tables so I can track what users inserted/updated records in my database. I did this as I prefer using INT fields for primary keys. In this scenario everything is working fine.

I am now thinking of using an external identity provider such as Azure Active Directory however I cannot work out how I would link a user in Azure AD (or any other identity provider) to my local database tables to maintain the user id foreign key constraints. From all my research I cannot find any articles for this scenario.

**How can I link user info from an external identity provider to my local database tables? I am worried that I might need to double handle the user account management in both the external identity provider and my local AspNet user tables to maintain the foreign keys with my other custom tables which seems crazy.**

Perhaps i'm missing something obvious or my approach is all wrong so if there is a better alternative for tracking who did what in my database tables for an ASP Net Core web application using an external identity provider I would happily adopt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to additional steps to link the user info for the user from external identity provider. It should looks be same for the web app.

When the users login from external identity provider, it still require to register the users to bind the user with individual accounts. The only difference is that there is no password for this kind of individual account and it can match the record in the `AspNetUserLogins`.  Here are two accounts, one is binding to the external identity provider and the other is not:

[image]

Comment: That makes sense however does this mean the AspNetUsers table is redundant? If all the user information can come from the identify provider then I assume I can add my INT PK as an extra field to the AspNetUserLogins table instead which can link to my other custom tables and therefore I can dump all the other AspNet* tables.

Comment: It is not redundant. All the user information is from `AspNetUsers ` table. The `AspNetUserLogins` is only for the account from external identity data provider.

Comment: What is the benefit of storing user information in both local identity table (AspNetUsers) and external identity provider? Won't this just duplicate the user data and require extra maintenance?

Comment: What's user data did you mean for duplicate?  The `AspNetUserLogins` is store the info about loginProvider.

Comment: Perhaps my understanding is wrong but I am referring to the AspNetUsers table not the AspNetUserLogins table. Won't the IDP store the same information as the AspNetUsers table? If so why keep the AspNetUsers table?

Comment: Based on my understanding, the Asp.net identity doesn't know which external identity data provider the web app will use. Also it is not able guarantee that all the user info in the Asp.net identity could be match using the external identity data provider. So the best practice for this using the `AspNetUsers` to store the user info and if the account is from external identity data provider, match the claims as much possible and also users can update other info if the identity data provider doesn't provider.

Comment: So that the user looks always to be same to the web app since the web app will look the user only in the `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: ok thanks that makes a lot more sense now. However at what point is a new user created in AspNetUsers and AspNetUserLogins table after being created in external IDP. Is it part of the registration process that would redirect to external IDP which returns a new identity and if that identity cannot be found in AspNetUserLogins table then create a new record in both AspNetUsers and AspNetUserLogins tables?

Comment: @OjM, did you determine a path forward on this implementation? I am facing the same issues and have not determined a path forward.

Comment: @Thomas Although quite some time ago what I did was hook into the OpenIdConnectOptions events with OnTokenValidated and grab the AAD id (along with other user properties) from the claims principal (`principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")`). Then I will call my service that adds or updates the user in my local db (`await context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>().CreateUser(model);`). Hope this helps

Comment: This makes sense; this is the path I was considering. I will likely go this route as well and thank you for your response.